# searching an array and compare them

Tags: c++, arrays

Write a program which takes two integer arrays from
user (max. 50 members each). First array should be longer than
the second one; then checks if all members in second array exist
in first one, in the same order, regardless of distance between
members in first array. Finally, program tells user whether this
condition is on or not .

Comment: Can you give a (short) example of array values that you expect to see?

Comment: welcome
dear user!
How many members in first array? 10
Enter member 1 of array 1:20
Enter member2 of array 1:1
Enter member 3 of array 1:16
Enter member 4 of array 1:5
Enter member 5 of array 1:9
Enter member 6 of array 1:12
Enter member 7 of array 1:25
Enter member 8 of array 1: 60
Enter member 9 of array 1:2
Enter member 10 of array 1:27
How many members in second array? 5
Enter member 1 of array 2:1
Enter member 2 of array 2:5
Enter member 3 of array 2:25
Enter member 4 of array 2:12
Enter member 5 of array 2:2
Condition is NOT on! Press any key to exit

Comment: @MatsPetersson is that ok ? i want to sent a screen shot but I couldnt

Comment: It would be much better if you actually edited your post to add what the vector looks like to the original question - a comment is pretty poor on formatting, making it very hard to read.

Comment: @MatsPetersson it seems that I can not send an image unless I have 10 reputation !!! how can I show you the example?

Comment: @SaraMehr: If you are in Windows, right click on the title bar of the window, select "Edit | mark".  Highlight the text, then press enter.  The text will be on the clipboard.  you can paste the text into your favorite editor.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the arrays makes no difference, as long as you know their lengths.  You have to check for going past them anyway.

Here's an algorithm:

```
if length of array2 is greater than 1, end.  // All of array can't be in array 1.

// Find the first element of array 2 that is in array 1:
// Note:  this only searches up to array1.length - array2.length,
//        because of the restriction of ordering and length of array 2.
key = first element of array 2.
found = false;
for (index = 0; index < (array1.length - array2.length); ++index)
  if (array[index] == key) then found = true, break out of loop. 
  end-for
if not found, end.  // No use in detailed searching.

// Now compare the elements of the two arrays, one by one, 
// starting with the second element of array2 and the element
// of array1 at (index + 1).
```

There are more efficient algorithms, but this should get you started until somebody posts the exact code so you don't have to do any work on your own.

Comment: Thnx for youre help ! actually I write it my self but I have some problems with it !!